# Comparing and reporting differing data between two databases

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sql-server-2008, reflection

The database for my application contains tables (not editable by the user) that are necessary for my application to run.  For instance, there is a **Report** table containing a list of my SSRS reports.

Except for the Auto-Increment and GUID fields, the data in my **Report** Table should match across all databases.

To keep existing client databases in synch with the ones created from scratch, there is a database updater app that runs scripts to update the existing client base.

There are Unit Tests to ensure Reports run correctly on both types of databases.  However, other than developer eye, there is no system check to ensure the rows and values in those rows match among the tables.  This is prone to human error.

To fix, I plan to add a small report to Unit Test report that will inform development of the following:

1. Records missing from the "Made From Scratch" database that exist in the "Updated" Database
2. Records missing from the "Updated" database that exist in the "Made From Scratch" Database
3. Fields that do not match between the tables

So far, I have a query to report the above information for all tables involved.

A sample query would look something like this:

```
--Take the fields I want to compare from TableToCompare in MadeFromScratch and put them in @First_Table_Var
--NOTE:  MyFirstField should match in both tables in order to compare the values between rows
DECLARE @First_Table_Var table(
    MyFirstField Varchar(255),
    MySecondField VarChar(255),
    MyThirdField Varchar(255),
    );

INSERT INTO @First_Table_Var
    SELECT
        r.MyFirstField,
        r.MySecondField,
        l.MyThirdField
    FROM
        MadeFromScratch.dbo.TableToCompare r
            INNER JOIN  MadeFromScratch.dbo.LookUpTable l ON r.ForeignKeyID = l.PrimaryKeyID


--Take the fields I want to compare from TableToCompare in UpdatdDatabase and put them in @Second_Table_Var
DECLARE @Second_Table_Var table(
    MyFirstField Varchar(255),
    MySecondField VarChar(255),
    MyThirdField Varchar(255),
    );

INSERT INTO @Second_Table_Var
    SELECT
        r.MyFirstField,
        r.MySecondField,
        l.MyThirdField
    FROM
        UpdatdDatabase.dbo.TableToCompare r
            INNER JOIN  UpdatdDatabase.dbo.LookUpTable l ON r.ForeignKeyID = l.PrimaryKeyID

--**********************
--   CREATE OUTPUT
--**********************

--List Rows that exist in @Second_Table but not @First_Table
--(e.g. these rows need to be added to the table in MadeFromScratch)
SELECT 
    Problem = '1 MISSING ROW IN A MADE-FROM-SCRATCH DATABASE',
    hur.MyFirstField,
    hur.MySecondField,
    hur.MyThirdField
FROM 
    @Second_Table_Var hur
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 
        *
     FROM 
        @First_Table_Var hu 
     WHERE
        hu.MyFirstField = hur.MyFirstField
    )

UNION

--List Rows that exist in @First_Table but not @Second_Table
--(e.g. these rows need to be added to the table in UpdatdDatabase)
SELECT 
    Problem = '2 MISSING IN UPDATE DATABASE',
    hur.MyFirstField,
    hur.MySecondField,
    hur.MyThirdField
FROM 
    @First_Table_Var hur
 WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 
        * 
     FROM
        @Second_Table_Var hu 
     WHERE
        hu.MySecondField = hur.MySecondField 
    )

UNION   

--Compare fields among the tables where MyFirstField matches, but 
SELECT 
    Problem = '3 MISMATCHED FIELD',
    h.MyFirstField,
    MySecondField = CASE WHEN h.MySecondField = hu.MySecondField    THEN '' ELSE 'Created Value:  ' + h.MySecondField                       + '  Updated Value:  '  + hu.MySecondField                  END,
    MyThirdField    = CASE WHEN h.MyThirdField = hu.MyThirdField        THEN '' ELSE 'Created Value:  ' + CAST(h.MyThirdField AS VARCHAR(4))    + '  Updated Value:  '  + CAST(hu.MyThirdField AS VARCHAR(4))   END,

 FROM
    @First_Table_Var h
        INNER JOIN @Second_Table_Var hu on h.MyFirstField  = hu.MyFirstField
 WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 
        *
     FROM
        @Second_Table_Var hu 
     WHERE
        hu.MyFirstField = h.MyFirstField and 
        hu.MySecondField = h.MySecondField and
        hu.MyThirdField = h.MyThirdField and
    )

ORDER BY Problem
```

I won't have any problem writing code to parse through the results, but this methodology *feels* antiquated for the following reasons:

1. Several queries (which essentially do the same thing) will need to be written
2. Maintenance for this process can get cumbersome

I would like to be able to write something where the list of tables and fields to compare is maintained by some kind of file (XML?).  So, whether fields are added or changes all the user has to do is update this file.

Is there a way to use LINQ and/or Reflection (or any feature in .NET 4.0 for that matter) where I could compare tables between two databases and maintain them like I've listed above?

Ideas are welcome.  Ideas with an example would be great! :D

Comment: I find the hard to follow.  "Existing client databases in synch with the ones created from scratch."  One(s) plural.   Maybe give an example.

Comment: A few questions. Don't you use the guids for cross matching? Is this about more than one scratch databases existing simultaneously? Can't you just _replace_ the complete table contents in the scratch database?

Answer (score 0):

you said *"Except for the Auto-Increment and GUID fields, the data in my Report Table should match across all databases."*

I assume that these fields are ID fields, ideally, replication of the database should replicate the id fields too ensuring this will allow you to check for new inserts by ID, in case of updates, you can set a timestamp field for comparison.